# Add elements to xml file in WP7?

Tags: xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7

How do you add an element to an xml file in wp7? I HAVE found alot of sources that show how to add elements in ASP.NET, Silverlight on the browser, etc.. but nothing on wp7. I keep seeing that we're supposed to use XDocument(XML to Linq), just not sure where to start. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XDocument usage on WP7 is the same as it is for silverlight.  Try something like this:

```
string xmlStr = "<RootNode><ChildNode>Hello</ChildNode></RootNode>";
XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
document.Root.Add(new XElement("ChildNode", "World!"));
string newXmlStr = document.ToString(); 
// The value of newXmlStr is now: "<RootNode><ChildNode>Hello</ChildNode><ChildNode>World!</ChildNode></RootNode>"
```

Comment: Yes that works, now how would I go about saving the changes to the xml file?

Comment: Try document.Save(<filestream>), where <filestream> is a stream for the file you want to save as.  To get a stream for a file in isolated storage, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

Comment: @ Matt Bridges :Using this i can edit xml thanks  .if i want to create new Xml file...and then need to add element inside that ....idea plz

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've been developing for WP7:

```
using (var store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
{
    using (var fs = store.OpenFile("MyXmlFile.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        var root = new XElement("Root");
        var someAttribute = new XAttribute("SomeAttribute", "Some Attribute Value");
        var child = new XElement("Child", "Child Value");
        var anotherChild = new XElement("AnotherChild", "Another Child Value");
        var xDoc = new XDocument();
        root.Add(someAttribute, child, anotherChild);
        xDoc.Add(root);
        xDoc.Save(fs);
    }
}
```