# Xml file Creation in Windows phone 7 app using Visual Studio 2010 C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have created XML successfully using Visual Studio 2008, but the same syntax does not appear to be supported for a Windows Phone 7 application in Visual Studio 2010.

I am using the following namespaces:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;
```

My code is:

```
private const string filename = @"c:\sampledata.xml";


XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.Indent = true;
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
settings.NewLineOnAttributes = true;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filename);
MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(strm, settings);
writer.WriteStartDocument(true);
writer.WriteComment("sample XML");
writer.WriteStartElement("root-node");
writer.WriteElementString("child-node", "The element value");
writer.WriteStartElement("next-child");
writer.WriteAttributeString("some-attribute", "A value");
writer.WriteAttributeString("another-attribute", "Another value");
writer.WriteValue("The next element value");
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.WriteEndDocument();
writer.Close();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Memory stream is not expandable

When  I Google it, I can't find a solution. I don't know whether my approach is correct or not. Please guide me to proceed further....

Answer (score 2):

When you created the MemoryStream, you used the ctor that initializes with a byte array.  This creates a non-resizable instance which has a maximum capacity as large as what it was initialized to.

Either create the MemoryStream using a different constructor or ensure that what you are writing isn't larger than the original byte[] size.

Comment: How to ensure that writing file is larger than the original byte size

Comment: Before getting too far down this road, I believe you are coding for WP7, in which case, you need to read/write from isolated storage. Follow the example in the last answer in this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083169/add-elements-to-xml-file-in-wp7)