# Can not save string / node to XML WP8

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, linq-to-xml

I am reading the contents of an xml file perfectly into a longlistselector with tap events attached. All working great. The file sits in the main assets folder of the project.

Now i would also like to add strings/ nodes to my simple XML, but for some reason i can't find the right syntax to save it to the file.

My xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<phrases>
<item><name>What is your name?</name></item>
<item><name>How old are you?</name></item>
</phrases>
```

Now I tried the following inside of a click event of a button:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("phrases.xml");
var contactsElement = new XElement("item", 
                                  new XElement("name", "blalllllaaaallaala")));
 xDoc.Add(contactsElement);
 xDoc.Save("phrases.xml");
```

VS2013 tells me that the xDoc.Save("phrases.xml") has invalid arguments. When i read from that file i provide the same path, so i dont understand what is expected here? Please give some suggestions.

Comment: Are you sure that you have write permissions for the file?

Comment: I am not sure. How can i check that and how can i give write permission?

Answer (score 1):

Just try out with this `snippet`...

```
// load original XML from the stream
XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(stream);

// create a new parent XML structure (new root) and load the original nodes
var newXml = new XDocument(new XElement("Histories"));
newXml.Root.Add(loadedData.Root);

// create the new node
var contactsElement = new XElement("item", 
                              new XElement("name", "blalllllaaaallaala")));
NewNode.Add(contactsElement);  

// add the new node
newXml.Root.Add(NewNode);

// save the stream
newXml.Save(stream);
```

For more have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083169/add-elements-to-xml-file-in-wp7) too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and it would work! The problem was the file being in the assets folder. There are no writing permissions though the failures should be clearer on that. I had to first copy it to isolated storage and then work on the file from there.